# How to properly reuse modal views/controllers in a storyboard iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c

So in my application I have a wizard type flow embedded in a navigation controller, pretty standard app design, and it's working fine.

So my design issue at this point is I need to introduce "Dates" and Date selection at each point in the wizard, previously I was just timestamping everything to `DateTime.Now()` on the server side, but this needs to be editable by users now.

I can't seem to understand the proper way to do this with storyboards, I want to just put one "placeholder" Datepicker view on the storyboard somewhere and re-use it.  I don't want to create a segue and date picker view for EVERY SINGLE PAGE on the wizard, which is what I do now, it's terrible.

So I tried to get it to work as follows:

I have a generic date picker control, and use the following code to pull it up:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GenericDate"];

[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This pulls up the view, and I can select a date, however there are a few problems:

1. It's not part of the "navigation controller", or the flow of the wizard
2. I don't really know how to "respond" to the result of the date picker even if it was properly embedded in the nag controller

If someone can properly explain to me how to reuse "component views" inside of a storyboard flow I would appreciate.

At this point segues and view controllers only make sense if they are unique, I can't quite follow how to make them reusable components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it with storyboards, then one answer is this:

1. Create one controller with the datepicker in it
2. Create a delegate protocol in the datepicker controller (add this just below your imports in your XYZDatePicker.h):

   ```
   #import<UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @protocol DatePickerDelegate;

   @interface XYZDatePicker : UIViewController

   @property (nonatomic,weak)id<DatePickerDelegate> delegate;

   @end

   @protocol DatePickerDelegate<NSObject>
   -(void)datePickerViewController:(XYZDatePicker*)datePicker didPickDate:(NSDate*)date;
   @end
   ```
3. Create a property in the date picker to set the delegate protocol (see above)
4. Connect a modal segue from each viewcontroller where you need the picker to the
   datepicker controller
5. Implement the protocol in each vc that uses the datepicker.  This tells declares to other classes that you confirm to the protocol. (in your calling vc .h file import the DatePicker and add the delegate to the interface line):

   ```
   #import XYZDatePicker.h

   @interface XYZCallingViewController : UIViewController<XYZDatePickerDelegate>
   ```
6. In the 'prepareForSegue' method of each calling vc, set the vc as the delegate for the date picker
7. After you have picked the date in the datepicker, you can call the delegate protocol and it will return the selected values to the calling vc (add below to your XYZDatePicker.m where 'date' is the date you want to return to the calling VC):

   ```
   if([self.delegate respondsToSelector@selector(datePickerViewController:didPickDate:)] {
       [self.delegate datePickerViewController:self didPickDate:date];
   }
   ```
8. In your calling VC .m file you need to implement the protocol method that you declared in your .h file you conform to.   This is where the date value will be returned to you:

   ```
   -(void)datePickerViewController:(XYZDatePicker*)datePicker didPickDate:(NSDate*)date {
       //dismiss the date picker
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {
            //you may need to wait to call other UI transitions until this completes so you can put them in this block (or can set '...completion:nil];' if you don't need it
       }];

       if(date) {
           //do something with the date
       } else {
           //if date=nil then the user cancelled (assuming you use this same delegate method if you allow the user to cancel picking the date)
       }
   }
   ```

Another way to do it is to layout your datepicker in the storyboard and then instantiate it and present it from the calling vc.   You will still need the delegate protocol to return the selected value.   This eliminates the segues (steps 4 and 6).

Links to references/tutorials:

- [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)
- Ray Wenderlich's [Design Pattern](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns) tutorial is worth reading and touches on it (scroll down to 'Delegation').

Comment: This sounds like just what I'm looking for, do you have any hints or sample code how to create delegates in the modal controller?  I haven't really done anything with custom delegates before, just used ib outlets, any tutorial links or any hints you have with delegates is appreciated!!!

Comment: I added some links to a couple of good references to start with.

Comment: ...and added some proto code.  Could be typos but should give you the gist.  Still recommend looking at the links.  Good Luck!